# How do I export the data generated by this code to a CSV file in puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, csv, web-scraping, export-to-csv, puppeteer

I need to export the data generated by this code into a CSV file. I am new to node.js/puppeteer so I am struggling on generating a CSV file.

I understand I can use the fs write function and tried adding this to the end of my code to no avail:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const csv = await page.$$eval('.product_desc_txt', function(products){

 // Iterate over product descriptions
    let csvLines = products.map(function(product){

    // Inside of each product find product SKU and its price
        let productId = document.querySelector(".custom-body-copy").innerText.trim();
        let productPrice = document.querySelector("span[data-wishlist-linkfee]").innerText.trim();

    // Fomrat them as a csv line
        return `${productId};${productPrice}`;
    });
     // Join all lines into one file
     return csvLines.join("\n");
     });
    fs.writeFileSync("test.csv", csv)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got csv with data from puppeteer, but don't use it. Just write the data to file:

```
fs.writeFileSync("test.csv", csv);
```

Also writing to file this

```
'${productId};${productPrice}'
```

won't work, there are no such variables at that place and even if there were, the correct way to format variables into a string is with backticks:

```
`${productId};${productPrice}`
```

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to get the CSV file created but it is showing up blank.  I edited my code above, I don't believe it is catching the first const csv function.

Comment: Do I need to use fs.writeFile instead?

Comment: *but it is showing up blank* maybe `csv` variable is blank? have you checked it with console.log?